# Visual Studio C# Capturing Enter Key In Textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to capture the Enter key in a Windows Forms Textbox.  I got this fragment of code from a tutorial:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //
    // Detect the KeyEventArg's key enumerated constant.
    //
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed enter! Good job!");
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed escape! What's wrong?");
    }
}
```

but now my code throws a compile/build error:

```
The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Enter' can only appear on the left hand
side of += or -=    Line 44 Column 84
```

On the one hand I don't understand the error message.  On the other hand line 44 is a blank line having only a newline character.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: The problem is in the .designer.cs file. Try unsubscribing and resubscribing to the event.

Comment: Code shown here looks ok. How do you subscribe to your event and what's on lines 43,44 and 45?

Comment: Better yet:
Here's lines 43, 44, 45:
`
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
`
The curly brace on line 43 is the closing brace to the code above.  I'm not sure if I am subscribing to this event or not I just copied the code off of a tutorial.
This doesn't show up very well.  Line 43 is the curly brace.  Line 44 is blank. Line 45 is the method prototype.

Comment: Ignore my previous comments.  I was looking in the wrong file. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Designer file (form.Designer.cs)

Your Designer should be:

```
this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
```

You may have subscribed to the Enter event. That is actually not the Enter key. That is for being on it, and it is paired with the Leave event.